# Find out which voice channels your users are participating in (discord py)

Tags: discord.py

I want to get the ID of the voice channel the user using the current command is participating in.

I got the user's id through interaciton, but I don't know how to find the id of the participating channel.

```
@tree.command(guild=discord.Object(id=secrets.get('discordsv')), name='randomteam', description='We randomly assign people in the current call room.')
async def randomTeamSet(interaction: discord.Interaction, count: int):
    if count <= 1:
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"The number of teams is 2 or more.", ephemeral=True)
    else:
        #Command user's voice channel
        print("player voice channel is ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
userChannel = interaction.user.voice.channel.id
```

It should be noted this will error if they are not in a channel.